# Formatting null time in RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc, timespan

I am bringing back time values from a record set into an RDLC report. (c# Visual Studio 2013)
They are coming is as a nullable Timespan.
Which i display as HH:MM

This all looks fine until i get a null , if there is no time for record a null is returned,as it's a nullable timespan type. When this happens i get an #error in the RDLC report. What i want to happen is either show "00:00" , or just blank.

I have tried adding an IFF to the Expression field in RDLC so that if a null is returned i show nothing , or "00:00" , but both return the same result , a #error in the field.

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value),nothing,Format(TimeValue(Fields!Hours.Value.ToString),"hh:mm"))
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

**Solution update:**

Thanks for all your help :
This is the final expression i used to get this working in my case:

```
=IIF(Fields!Hours.Value.ToString = "00:00:00","",Format(TimeValue(Fields!Hours.Value.ToString),"hh:mm"))
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but your solution doesn't work for me - the ``Fields!Hours.Value.ToString`` in the 3rd param of ``IIF()`` causes an ``#error`` anytime ``Hours`` is null.

Comment: @Conrad did you try Thorsten's answer below, maybe his will work for you?

Comment: That didn't work either. I ended un-nulling the value upstream as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `nothing` value with an empty string. Also use `X is nothing` instead of `ISNOTHING(x)`:

```
=IIF(Fields!Hours.Value is nothing,"",Format(TimeValue(Fields!Hours.Value.ToString),"hh:mm"))
```

The fact that you get `#error` no matter what you tried makes me wonder whether the expression is correct at all or if you have something going on in addition, like automatic formatting or stuff like that.

Please try to use this expression on the foreground color and set the color to `Red` in case the value is `null` and `Green` in case it is not. Also check whether there's some display format selected that could cause errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help Thorsten, you're right, i think there was something else wrong here,it just wasn't falling into my "is nothing" part of the IIF statement, i.e. it was never seeing the TimeSpan as being null even though it was. In the end i got this working by using a slight variation on your answer so i'll mark yours correct. What worked for me what instead of checking null , i now check="00:00:00" , why i had to do this i do not know but this worked for me : =IIF(Fields!Hours.Value.ToString = "00:00:00","",Format(TimeValue(Fields!Hours.Value.ToString),"hh:mm"))

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use two overlapping text boxes in the container with visibility conditions based on value of Hours field.

One would display your formatted Timespan:

```
= Format(TimeValue(Fields!Hours.Value.ToString),"hh:mm")
```

With visibility expression (True for hidden):

```
= IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value), True, False)
```

If you don't need to display some value (like "-") in case of null Timespan, you don't need second text box, but if you do - second text box would display your "nothing" string:

```
= "nothing string"
```

And visibility expression for it would be:

```
= IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Hours.Value), False, True)
```

Comment: Why? Had to do it number of times, never had a problem

Comment: Overlapping elements caused all kinds of rendering errors in our reports and they are so *not* easily maintainable, especially when aligned. The better solution is to get your expression right.

Comment: @Alicia, I would clarify that it is not the VISIBILITY property, but the HIDDEN property in the report (under the Visibility section).  By default, HIDDEN is FALSE (don't hide).  Change it to TRUE based on your NULL value of the column in question.

Comment: Thanks for the help InitKnit, but i managed to get it working by using Thorsten solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Thorsten Dittmar's solution worked for me but I think the key is to remove the TimeValue or DateValue expressions in the IIF.

I was originally doing the same to return a Date or Time and then using the Textbox format option to add the formatting.  However, when the field value is Null, TimeValue or DateValue returned an error, suggesting the iif statement evaluates both results regardless.

Anyway, this works (for me):

```
=iif(Fields!DateRequired.Value is nothing, nothing, Format(Fields!DateRequired.Value,"HH:mm"))
```