# Converting to Date format shows #VALUE! in Excel rdlc report

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, excel, rdlc

I am trying to generate excel file from an RDLC report where a column in the report table converts a string value to DateTime like below

```
=IIF(Fields!WeldDate.Value is nothing, nothing, Format(CDate(Fields!WeldDate.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
```

if the WeldDate is an empty string then Excel data shows #VALUE!. how can I fix this?

P.S: I have also tried below as well.

```
=IIF(Fields!WeldDate.Value is "", "", Format(CDate(Fields!WeldDate.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
```

Comment: But I have an if condition. if the date value is nothing/"" then return nothing or ""

Comment: but when I see the column type of that column in Excel it still appears as "General" instead of Date

Comment: Well `#Value!` Indicates a value error

Comment: In VBA, the `IIf` function evaluates both `true_part` and `false_part` always.  If either could return an error, you need to use an `If ...Then ... Else ... End If` structure.  Could this be the same issue in your language?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
=IIf(Len(Fields!WeldDate.Value) > 0, Format(CDate(Fields!WeldDate.Value), "dd/MM/yyyy"), "")
```

Or check this out, this seems to be a very similar issue:
[Formatting null time in RDLC report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796302/formatting-null-time-in-rdlc-report)

Comment: Shows the same result